# Cannot get value from simple form user input in Spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement a login form in a Spring boot application. It has an email and a password field. The email field failed to get user input, here is the form:

```
  <form th:action="@{/login}" method="get" th:object="${loginForm}" style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="m-3">

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">E-mail: </label>
        <div class="col-8">
          <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" name="q" class="form-control" required />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Password: </label>
        <div class="col-8">
          <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Here is the controller:

```
    @GetMapping("login")
    public ModelAndView login(Model model, @RequestParam(name = "q", required = false) Optional<String> email) {
        Optional<UserDto> aUser;
        System.out.println(email);
        if (email.isPresent()) {
            aUser = userService.getAUserByEmail(email.get());
            model.addAttribute("user", aUser);
            var mv = new ModelAndView("user/user-list", model.asMap());
            return mv;
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("loginForm", new LoginForm());
            return new ModelAndView("/login/login-form", model.asMap());
        }
    }
```

I thought the `@RequestParam(name = "q")` and `name="q"` in html would do the job, but I always get `Optional.empty` for email. Any idea what's wrong here?

UPDATE:
From the answers I changed controller to this:

```
    @GetMapping("login")
    public ModelAndView login(Model model, LoginForm loginForm) {
        Optional<UserDto> aUser;
        if (loginForm.getEmail() != null) {
            aUser = userService.getAUserByEmail(loginForm.getEmail());
            model.addAttribute("user", aUser);
            var mv = new ModelAndView("user/user-list", model.asMap());
            return mv;
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("loginForm", new LoginForm());
            return new ModelAndView("/login/login-form", model.asMap());
        }
    }
```

`login-form.html` to this:

```
  <form th:action="@{/login}" method="get" th:object="${loginForm}" style="max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="m-3">

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">E-mail: </label>
        <div class="col-8">
          <input type="text" th:field="*{email}" class="form-control" required />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Password: </label>
        <div class="col-8">
          <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I also have `LoginForm.java` like this

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class LoginForm {
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

but still not getting user email field input?

Comment: th:object is normally used only in post requests (i.e. in form submission via a post request method). The reason, I think, is that objects can potentially get very big (including the payload) and a http get method has a limit of 2kB.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have set up your form, it's mapping the value of your email input field to the property `email` (that's what `th:field="*{email}"` means) of an object called `loginForm` (that's what `th:object="${loginForm}"` means). Neither of these seem to be used or even exist in your `login()` method. You need to either change what you use in your controller to match what you have in your Thymeleaf template, or change your Thymeleaf template to actually reference what you are using in your controller.

Comment: The form is named as `login-form.html`, any idea what I should add in the controller please?

Comment: `th:object` is unrelated to how your form is named (also, login-form.html is the name of your template, not of your form; in the code you posted the form is unnamed, and in fact it doesn't need a name). `th:object` is related to the parameter received by the method that is executed when you submit the form (i.e. the method specified by `th:action`), so your `login()` method needs to receive an object named `loginForm` of a type that has a field named `email`.

Comment: Still not working, could you check the updated question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is located under `th:object="${loginForm}"`

With this you inform spring to bind the data sent from the form into an object named `loginForm`.

So Spring actually expects the controller to be

```
@GetMapping("login")
    public ModelAndView login(Model model, LoginForm loginForm) {
   ....
```

and inside `LoginForm` a field named `email` will contain the value sent from the form, as you have declared with `<input type="text" th:field="*{email}" .... >`

If you don't want the data to be bound into an object from Spring Mvc then

1. remove the `th:object="${loginForm}"`
2. use the

   ```
    <input type="text" th:name="q" class="form-control" required />
   ```

   and then the controller will receive the sent value as a query parameter

   ```
       @GetMapping("login")
       public ModelAndView login(Model model, @RequestParam(name = 
       "q", required = false) Optional<String> email) {
   ```

Comment: Sorry tried it still got empty value

Comment: I tried both solutions: 1. remove the `th:object="${loginForm}"`, 2. keep `th:object="${loginForm}"` also adding `public ModelAndView login(Model model, LoginForm loginForm) {`, still not getting email input

Comment: @one-hand-octopus did you try with debug? Is the controller method even called? How are you testing it?

Comment: @one-hand-octopus for the first way with custom object mapping try to define your controller method as `@GetMapping("login")
    public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute LoginForm loginForm, Model model) {`

Comment: Yeah I tried debugging, with 2nd method the controller was called but the first `if` was never reached, i.e. email wasn't obtained from user input

Comment: For the first way, if I remove `th:object="${loginForm}"` I got this error `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'email' available as request attribute`

Comment: @one-hand-octopus for second workflow you need the controller to be `public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute LoginForm loginForm, Model model) {` you probably have it as  `public ModelAndView login(@ModelAttribute LoginForm email, Model model) {`

Comment: @one-hand-octopus for first workflow with request parameters check an example here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-request-parameters#parameters-in-forms . For second workflow with object binding check an example here https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc#input